# AutoMapper - Map Json string property to interface based object

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-6

I have a source class like this:

```
public partial class Source
{
    ...
    public int ScheduleBaseId { get; set; }
    public int ScheduleIncrement { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionTypeId { get; set; } // <- Determines the concrete class to map to
    public string SubscriptionCriteriaJson { get; set; } // <- Map to interface class
    ...
}
```

Which I'm mapping to this destination class:

```
public class Dest
{
    ...
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
    public ISubscriptionCriteria SubscriptionCriteria { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I'd like to map the `Source.SubscriptionCriteriaJson` property to `Dest.SubscriptionCriteria` which uses an interface. The concrete class for the interface can be determined using `Source.SubscriptionTypeId`. There's two issues in tandem I'm trying to resolve here for mapping to `SubscriptionCriteria`:

1. De-serializing the json string to a `ISubscriptionCriteria` object.
2. Mapping to the correct concrete type for `ISubscriptionCriteria` based on `SubscriptionTypeId`.

Any ideas / pointers how I achieve this in AutoMapper? I'm new to AutoMapper so am still feeling my way around.

This is what I have so far for the rest of the mapping:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Schedule, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => new Schedule((ScheduleBaseEnum)src.ScheduleBaseId, src.ScheduleIncrement)); })
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this in the following way:

```
public class AutoMapperProfileConfiguration : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfileConfiguration()
        : this("MyProfile")
    {
    }

    protected AutoMapperProfileConfiguration(string profileName)
        : base(profileName)
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Schedule, opt =>
            {
                opt.MapFrom(src => new Schedule((ScheduleBaseEnum)src.ScheduleBaseId, src.ScheduleIncrement));
            })
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SubscriptionCriteria, opt =>
            {
                opt.MapFrom(src => (ISubscriptionCriteria)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(src.SubscriptionCriteriaJson, GetSubscriptionCriteriaType((SubscriptionTypeEnum)src.SubscriptionTypeId)));
            });
    }

    private Type GetSubscriptionCriteriaType(SubscriptionTypeEnum type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case SubscriptionTypeEnum.SomeType1:
                return typeof(SomeType1);
            case SubscriptionTypeEnum.SomeType2:
                return typeof(SomeType2);
            ...
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("SubscriptionType of {0} is not implemented.", Enum.GetName(typeof(SubscriptionTypeEnum), type)));
        }
    }
}
```

If there's a more elegant solution you can think of please share I'm keen to learn!